# how to get only 2nd level category to side bar in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want only: Sub-1.1, Sub-1.2 and Sub-2.1

Cat 1

Sub-1.1

Sub-1.2

```
   Sub-1.2.1
```

Cat 2

Sub-2.1

I don't want cat 1,cat2 and Sub-1.2.1

Thank You.
Dinesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single call. You can use the following logic

- Get all the parent categories
- Loop through all of them and get their first level sub-categories

You can get all the parent categories using

```
$parent_cats = get_categories('parent=0');
```

Then loop the list of $parent_cats and use the following to get it's direct children

```
$child_cats = get_categories('child_of=' . $parent_cats[$i] . '&parent=' . $parent_cats[$i]);
```